# Using custom function in mutate() with dplyr & monetDB

Tags: r, monetdb, monetdblite

I am just beginning to discover all the advantages of using `R` & `monetDB`/`monetDBLite` package - great stuff!
I was curious however if it's possible to use a custom defined function in `dplyr`'s `mutate()` i.e.

```
# Connect to monetDBLite
db <- src_monetdb(embedded = db.dir)
data <- tbl(db, "my.table")

# Try to make a new column using custom defined function  
data %>% group_by(colX) %>% mutate(NewCol = customFunc())
```

Results in the following error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
Unable to execute statement 'SELECT colA colB colC...'.
Server says 'ParseException:SQLparser:SELECT: no such operator 'customFunc''.
```

It seems like the SQL parser has a problem finding the custom function. Am I overseeing something (declare `R` code in a `SQL` function definition etc.) ? Is it possible to use custom defined functions with the `monetDBLite` package like this?

Comment: How is `customFunc` defined? Generally you need to pass summary functions an argument, i.e. a column to operate on.

Comment: This is not yet supported. Throw in a `collect()` in between perhaps? Transfers should be pretty fast, especially when you `select()` only the columns you need before.

Comment: @HannesMühleisen yes, that works pretty good. Any plans on implementing this in the future? Also, does it make a difference that I'm using the `monetDBLite` package - is this possible with a 'real' `monetDB` setup? Thank you and keep up the great work!

Comment: In addition dplyr can always send arbitrary SQL to the database, as explain in the [dplyr database vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html): `tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))`. This looses all the benefit of dplyr verbs but it's possible.

Comment: yes you are right but i guess this is more aimed at using some DB functions not covered by `dplyr` or using functions defined for some DBs but not for others. There is an example with using `%like%` in the vignette you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Hannes answered my question in the comments - i'm adding it here with some other stuff i picked up:

- one can use the basic `dplyr` verbs (`select`, `filter`, `group_by` & `mutate`) in conjunction with some other "basic" `R` functions. There is a list of the supported functions, and more on this, in the `dplyr` [databases vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) under the section "SQL translation". So, using the example from my question above - one can do:
  `data %>% group_by(col_x) %>% mutate(new_col = log10(some_old_col))`.
- `MonetDBLite` does not support UDFs (e.g. my question here - if it's possible to use my UDF inside a `mutate` call) ...
- ... however the "full" `MonetDB` does support used defined functions to be sent to the db for computation. It is all well explained on their [homepage](https://www.monetdb.org/content/embedded-r-monetdb).